# How to start `mockjax` back after `stop`

Tags: mockjax

In my application I have a shuffle button to start and stop the `mockjax` response. as a first time, I am initiating the mockjax it works. later the user click on `off` button to stop `mockjax` service. ( I am showing server data )

for stop I use:

```
stopSimulation : function( ) {

            if( !this.retriveSimulationStatus() ) {
                console.log("i switched off!!");
                $.mockjax.clear(); //removes the simulation; 
            }

        }
```

But user clicks back to `start` button, But `mockjax` not intercepting again to provide the data.

so what is the correct way to stop and start the `mockjax` service? any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the Mockjax handlers does NOT "stop" them, it erases them from Mockjax. There is no "start"/"stop" functionality. You will need to clear the handlers, then re-add the handlers when you want to start. Here's an example:

```
var handler = { url: '/foo', responseText: { foo: 'bar' } };

function start() {
  $.mockjax(handler);
}

function stop() {
  $.mockjax.clear();
}
```